# Google time and answer mistakes

Tags: bug, google

Take a look a this :

[image]

On the google search page I can see

- 13 hours ago
- 1 answer

When I actually [posted the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761253/waitforexit-process-ends-when-application-lose-focus) :

- 8 mins ago
- 0 answers

This should be fixed.

Comment: First of all, you need to know who to blame. Google? Or SO?

Comment: `"Go fix Google"` good luck with that.

Comment: @Servy To be fair, Google *does* acknowledge a *ton* of microformats which it uses to enhance its search results, embedding them in the question might not be the worst idea.

Comment: I wonder where all the downvotes come from. Is this really that bad a question?

Comment: @casperOne I know, I just couldn't resist.

Comment: @MrLister By all, you mean the *one* downvote?

Comment: Here's the page for Google that indicates what microformats they currently support: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146897

Comment: @Servy Oh sorry, I was looking 13 hours from now. My bad.

Comment: Hmm. Odd. I currently get *two* results - both for the same page. If I can still reproduce it next time I'm on my work laptop, I'll mail the search team. No promises - and I very much doubt that I'll be able to feed anything back - but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for wishing me luck ;)

Comment: Ooh, that will be a new entry to the "John Skeet Facts" question. Jon Skeet can fix Google.