# Duplicate behaviour on mobile

Tags: support, questions

If I go into my profile -> questions and click on one of my question that was marked as duplicate,
I can still access my question but see a little box at the beginning pointing out that my question is a dupe.

> [image]

[Google time and answer mistakes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166696/google-time-and-answer-mistakes)

The thing is, if I access it the same way (profile -> questions) from my android device, **I cannot see my question** it automatically brings me to the question that was asked first. In this case :

[Google doesn't know how to count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115634/google-doesnt-know-how-to-count)

Is this behavior on purpose? I'll tag it as bug to make sure.

Comment: Are you logged in on mobile?  It has always been the behavior of auto-redirecting to the canonical when the user is anonymous.

Comment: No I am not logged on. Also, no I was not aware of that feature. Thanks :)

Comment: @Servy when did they set that up?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA It's been around for quite some time.  Couldn't tell you an exact date.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not logged into the site, and are instead viewing it anonymously, anytime you go to a question that is closed as a duplicate you will be automatically redirected to the canonical question.  This is true both on mobile and on the non-mobile versions of the site.